# how to know data is updated or not while refresh using webserivce

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, caching

I am bit new in iPhone/iOS.
and want to implement to check that data has been updated/modified or not after refresh so that if it is not updated i doesn't need to load the data again.

Please suggest me a better way of doing so.

Comment: can you post the code related to the webService call

Comment: what kind of data you are talking about?

Comment: i am getting some data(JSON: 50 records) from server one my page is loaded 1st time. There is a Refresh button on the page that will call the service again and i want to check after Refresh that data has been updated/modified from last time's response or not before parsing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First time, take all the records from server along with the `server date`(check date parameter, if null then server passes all records i.e. first time app is launched).

2) Store that `date` in `NSUserDefaults`.

3) Second time pass that `date` while request, if `date` is not null(request is not first time).

4) Server checks the updated records(records greater than the `date` which you passed).

```
NSString *strTodaysDate = @"";
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SyncDone"] != nil)
{
     //If sync all data is done first time, then pass server date else pass empty date parameter.
     strTodaysDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SyncDate"]];
} //call web service with strTodaysDate as a parameter.
```

Comment: It is more useful bcz it gives u only updated records which avoids unwanted data transfer from server to device.